# getting r2 out of a summ.svyglm object

Tags: r

I am trying to get R² for survey-adjusted logistic models.  I am using jtools, which prints the Pseudo-R² and the observations to the screen, but I can't sort out how to extract those elements into a data.frame.

```
library(survey)
library(jtools)
data(api)
dstrat <- svydesign(id = ~1, strata =~ stype, weights =~ pw,
data = apistrat, fpc =~ fpc)
regmodel <- svyglm(as.numeric( both =="Yes") ~ ell * meals, design = dstrat, family="binomial" )
summ(regmodel)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are stored as attributes of the `summ(regmodel)` object.  The "Cragg-Uhler" value is in attribute `"rsq"`, and the "McFadden" one is in `"rsqmc"`.  You can extract them as numbers using

```
rsq <- attr(summ(regmodel), "rsq")
rsqmc <- attr(summ(regmodel), "rsqmc")
```

To find things like this, you need to look at the code that prints the results.  That's often `print.xxxx`, where `xxxx` is the class of the object.  Here `class(summ(regmodel))` is `c("summ.svyglm" "summ")`, so it will be `print.summ.svyglm` if there is such a thing, and `print.summ` if not.

Typically those functions aren't exported from a package, so if `print.summ.svyglm` doesn't find anything, you might still want to try `getAnywhere("print.summ.svyglm")`.  In this case that's what works.  You can read through that function and figure out where it got those values from.

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of these approaches:

```
library(survey)
library(jtools)
data(api)
dstrat <- svydesign(id = ~1, strata =~ stype, weights =~ pw,
                    data = apistrat, fpc =~ fpc)
regmodel <- svyglm(as.numeric( both =="Yes") ~ ell * meals, design = dstrat, family="binomial" )
```

Approach 1:

```
#Approach 1
attr(summ(regmodel), "rsq")
```

Output:

```
[1] 0.00107412
```

Approach 2:

```
#Approach 2
x <- capture.output(summ(regmodel))
x[9]
x[10]
```

Output:

```
[1] "Pseudo-R² (Cragg-Uhler) = 0.00"

[1] "Pseudo-R² (McFadden) = 0.01"
```